# Error with configuring thinking sphinx and flying sphinx

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have Rails 3 application running on Heroku. I am using `Thinking Sphinx` search engine into my application. For making it work with Heroku, I have added a `flying-sphinx` gem to my gemfile as suggested in the Heroku docs.

This is what I have in my gemfile

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.11' 
gem 'flying-sphinx',   '0.7.0'
```

As per the steps mentioned here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/flying_sphinx,
After adding the flying-sphinx addon (Heroku addons:add flying_sphinx:wooden),
when I run 
 heroku run flying-sphinx configure
I get following error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/sphinx_configuration.rb:2:in 'initialize': uninitialized constant FlyingSphinx::SphinxConfiguration::ThinkingSphinx (NameError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/cli.rb:31:in 'new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/cli.rb:31:in 'configure'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/cli.rb:20:in 'block in run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/cli.rb:20:in 'each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/cli.rb:20:in 'all?'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/lib/flying_sphinx/cli.rb:20:in 'run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/flying-sphinx-0.8.0/bin/flying-sphinx:5:in ''
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/flying-sphinx:19:in 'load'
    from vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/flying-sphinx:19:in ''
```

And I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: It appears that flying_sphinx is now at 0.8.5 (or there is 0.7.1). Maybe you can try updating the gem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Anyone come up with an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the original question - going by the stacktrace, if looks like you're using flying-sphinx 0.8.0 - which was definitely buggy, hence more recent releases. Hopefully you followed Bert's suggestion and gave 0.8.5 a spin (0.7.1 is the latest for Rails 2.3).

Answer (score 1):

My working Gemfile setup for rails 3:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', "~> 2.0.10", require: 'thinking_sphinx'
gem 'flying-sphinx',   '0.8.4'
```

or

```
# sphinx 
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.0.3'
gem 'flying-sphinx', '1.0.0'
```